# GCP: Can not ssh to instance after sftp setting (ForceCommand internal-sftp)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, sftp

After I added following lines to the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** for sftp setup as online guide suggested.

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I can not open ssh to instance with "**This service  allows sftp connections only**" message.
I guess ForceCommand internal-sftp limits ssh connection.
It's dummy that I blocked myself..
Is there way to fix this problem without lossing instance data? Any help will be highly appreciated. (Pics are captured from my gcp-cloudshell)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Login with a different user, that is not in the sftp group.

Comment: If Michael's suggestion does not work, this SO answer will help you save the data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700151/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for suggestion! I downloaded important files and moved it to new instance by sftp manually. I hope other user with similar problem would find some help from your link, thanks again.